# psfrag substitutions occur only sometime

Tags: texstudio, psfrag

I am using TeX studio and I am using the `dvi-->ps-->pdf` so that the `\psfrag` substitutions occur on my `.eps` figures. But they replace only some of the texts. For example, if I want to replace `O1` by `$O_1$`, it does not work. Instead if I type 'oaaa' in place of `O1` only then it works. This gets annoying as I have a lot of replacements to do and it would be a waste of time to keep trying until the substitutions occur. I searched a lot for this error in vain. Can anybody please help me with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the EPS file in a text editor, most likely that `(01)` does not appear as a single `()` delimited string but as two strings `(O)` and `(1)` positioned separately for kerning or other reasons. `psfrag` can not replace a text unless it is a single string in the original.

It is hard sometimes to control this in the application that you use to produce the EPS (one option is simply to edit the EPS file and change `(O)` to`(O1)` and `(1)` to `( )` so that psfrag has a string it can work with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer David. I opened the .eps file in a notepad and I do have single strings (O1) and yet the replacements are not occuring.